# continue script when javascript variable is empty

Tags: javascript

i have this redirect code

```
<script>
//get timezone offset
var tzd = new Date();
var tzo = -tzd.getTimezoneOffset() * 60; 

//redirect
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='savejs.php?to=https://test.com/" + "&tzo=" + tzo "'><\/script>");
</script>
```

the problem is when tzo variable is unknown (empty/undefined) it will break the redirect script. how to make sure the redirect continue even tzo variable is unknown.

the redirect script is inside savejs.php (because i want to make sure i get the tzo variable first before visitor allowed to continue)

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a small check of tzo if it is defined and if not, convert it to an empty string.

```
<script>
//get timezone offset
var tzd = new Date();
var tzo = -tzd.getTimezoneOffset() * 60; 

// make tzo to an empty string if not defined or null
tzo = tzo || "";

//redirect
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='savejs.php?to=https://test.com/" + "&tzo=" + tzo "'><\/script>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`try,catch,finally`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp):

```js
//get timezone offset
var tzd = new Date();
var tzo = 0
try {
  tzo = -tzd.getTimezoneOffset() * 60;
} catch (err) {
  tzo = 0; //when error occur
} finally {
  //redirect
  document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='savejs.php?to=https://test.com/" + "&tzo=" + tzo "'><\/script>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply validate the `tzo` with if condition .it validate `empty|null|undefined`

```
//get timezone offset
var tzd = new Date();
var tzo = -tzd.getTimezoneOffset() * 60; 
if(tzo){
//redirect
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='savejs.php?to=https://test.com/" + "&tzo=" + tzo "'><\/script>");
}
```

Comment: @downvoter please type the comment what wrong with answer

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from code provided what is breaking the script. In addition to current answers, you can try conditionally adding `tzo` url parameter:

```
//get timezone offset
var tzd = new Date();
var tzo = -tzd.getTimezoneOffset() * 60; 
var tzoParam = tzo ? "&tzo=" + tzo : "";

//redirect
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='savejs.php?to=https://test.com/" + tzoParam + "'><\/script>");
```